# Using gdb to read from a file descriptor in OSX

Tags: macos, gdb, file-descriptor

What i'm trying to do is replicating `cat /proc/{pid}/fd/{fd-id}` in OSX.

I get the idea that it can be done using gdb.

the process is.

Suppose i want to read from fd 34 of pid 4554.

1. run gdb and attach to pid 4554.
2. open a file using 'w' mode. (to write the data we read of {fd-id}. Suppose fd of this file is 65.
3. fseek fd 34 to 0.
4. Start a loop.
5. read some data from fd 34, save it to memory.
6. write the buffered data from memory to fd 65.
7. keep running this loop until EOF of fd 34 is reached.
8. Close fd 65.
9. detach from pid 4554 and close gdb.

Now i dont really know much gdb so can anyone say how to make the above steps in gdb command ?

Comment: Why do you get the idea that `gdb` can do this?

Comment: @trojanfoe I get some resources like this from google http://blog.tridgell.net/?p=4 . Which does a pretty similar task, so i assume my requirement can also be done with gdb.

Comment: Hmmm, that is interesting.  It looks possible yes.